# How to validate a URL that returns "403" error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-403

I am using XMLHTTP to get the html from site A.

```
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set htmldoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim xmlhttp As XMLHTTP60
Set xmlhttp = New XMLHTTP60

With xmlhttp
    .Open "GET", siteAurl, False
    .Send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

I am parsing the htmldoc to form a URL for site B like this: `https://www.siteb.com/year=2021/title_with_spaces_replaced_by_dashes.htm`

When I tried to use the script to validate the URL for site B, I kept getting an error. When I checked the response, it was "403 - forbidden". I searched for ways to get around this but the headers that I tried didn't work.

```
.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405"
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

When I copy/paste the generated URL in Chrome, it works so I know at least some of the URLs are valid.

As another test, I set up a simple script using Selenium webdriver. This was able to access the generated URL for site B.

```
Dim bot As WebDriver
Set bot = New WebDriver

With bot
    ' .AddArgument "--headless"
    .AddArgument ("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36")
    .Start "chrome"
    .Get siteBurl
End With ' bot
```

Question 1: Is there a way to modify the XMLHTTP request to validate the generated URL for site B?

Question 2: If not, is there a way to return a response status code with Selenium to validate the generated URL? My searches so far have returned solutions for C# and Java but nothing for VBA.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We cannot make reasonable suggestions on how to validate via the headers, for specific urls, as there is not enough info. Ideally, provide all the urls in question (examples of A and B). There are existing answers which cover doing a HEAD request and testing returned .status if that is what you need.

Comment: I guess if you don't want to make multiple requests, then wrap the code which does something with the response inside of a test of status = 200. Include a couple of links for what you found for C# / Java